# Foreach Loop in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have list of servers in String and want to iterate over the Servers. Below is my code

```
$nodeNames = "Ash","ASI"

foreach ($nodename in $nodeNames)
{
  Write-Output $nodeName
}
```

I am expecting that i should get $nodeName as Ash for first iteration and ASI for second iteration. But i am getting Ash ASI in my first iteration itself. Can any one help me on this.

I am using Powershell 5

Comment: How did you determine that both where output during the first iteration?

Comment: This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you *sure*?

Try instrumenting your code with something that can indicate whether that's actually the case or not:

```
$nodeNames = "Ash","ASI"

$counter = 0
foreach ($nodename in $nodeNames)
{
  $counter++
  Write-Output "Iteration ${counter}: $nodeName"
}
```

... which, in both Windows PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell 7.1 on my Windows 10 laptop gives me:

```
Iteration 1: Ash
Iteration 2: ASI
```